# Android Store something in Application Context

Tags: android, android-context

There is a lot of examples and guides how to get `ApplicationContext`, but a cannot find some examples which provide me an ability to store some values in `ApplicationContext`.
I want to get, for example, string mode everywhere in my application, like this:

```
String mode = getApplicationContext().getMode();
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to extend `Application` (there is no `ApplicationContext` class)  and add the fields you need stored to your custom class. Then you would cast the reference you get from `getApplication()` to your actual class:

```
class MyApplication extends Application {
  String mode;
}

// in your activity
MyApplication app = (MyApplication)getApplication();
String mode = app.mode;
```

Comment: In some class exists only getApplicationContext() method (eg NetworkReceiver), can I cast it to MyApplication?

Comment: Probably :) At least in 2.3 it is the same reference, and AFAIK there is only one instance of the application class. If you need to access your custom data from classes other than activities, another alternative would be to use a singleton class and not depend on the `Application` class.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you store it in shared preferences?